# 2D cross correlation code for small images

Tags: programming, sensors, ir

I am working on a arduino Uno project* to detect eye pupil movement and I am thinking of using a serial low-res jpeg camera. I am thinking of implementing a cross-correlation function to detect when the pupil is turned towards the camera.

I am looking, so far unsuccessfully, for a c source code that performs a 2D cross-correlation without using FFT (Fourier Transform). I think such code might have good enough performance even on an Arduino Uno board when running on a low-res image, something like a 32x32 pixels image.

I'd appreciate if you could direct me to such a piece of code or alternatively tell me that this can't be done on an Arduino board due to CPU\RAM limitations.

[Current Device is using an IR range finder to detect IR reflected from the retina when looking directly into the device.](https://www.youtube.com/watch?time_continue=26&v=iaICOBk-bmo)

P.S.

- The project is intended to provide ALS patients the capability to use eye-motion to call for help, using a low-cost device.

Comment: 32×32 is 1024 pixels. Assuming one byte per pixel, you would need 2 KiB only to store the two images you want to cross-correlate. And that's the total amount of RAM of an Arduino Uno, so you would have no RAM left for doing anything!

Comment: A Raspberry Pi is probably better suited to this task, IMHO.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's a pure programming question with no relationship to Ardunio